# .htaccess for images only upload

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, upload

I'm developing a very simple PHP upload feature in my site to permit users to upload JUST images. Apart from checking the mime-type through php I wanted a .htaccess file to rule what can be uploaded and what can't.
I want to insert the .htaccess in my root folder and from there writing the rules for all the folders I need to be ruled.

It's the first time I work with .htaccess and from the internet I was able to find this:
http://pastebin.com/0KNHEbw0

But it doesn't work. I'm testing it locally with my xampp on win7 and I see that I can upload any type of files in the "oggetti" folder.
What's that is wrong?

And then, to rule other folders should I write something like this?
http://pastebin.com/dFMUu1g0

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't control what files are uploaded through a `.htaccess` file: Apache, the web server parsing those commands, deals with *serving* the files only.

You will need to do these checks in the PHP script that handles the upload process. Note that checking the MIME type sent with the file is not a reliable method to determine a file's type! The value sent can be manipulated by an attacker. To ensure a file is an image file, you could e.g. use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize).

Comment: getimagesize isn't good in itself as well. As far as I know, it is possible to "hide" other files in images without making any of them corrupt. Only one method isn't enough, MIME type + getimagesize + checking extension should make it safe.

Comment: @axiomer but what good would it do for an attacker to hide a malicious file in an image? It would have to be executed in order to be harmful, and I know of no image library that has such a security hole.

Comment: @Andrea that looks okay to me.

Comment: Pekka: if they set image/jpeg for mimetype of PHP plus they hide it in an image, then without the extension check, the app will be able to run. So extension check is required as well.

Comment: @axiomer define "run". Run by whom? Which program or browser would run an executable inside an image file? All you will get is an invalid image file filled with garbage.

Comment: As I said, with the extension check, it works well. But if you do NOT check an extension, you can send to server a "so-called" image/jpeg, with extension of .php which is valid both as jpg and php. When opening, it will be interpreted as if it was .php. But the extension check solves the problem.

Comment: @axiomer ahh, you mean on the server side. Of course, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be accomplished using `.htaccess`. I'm guessing what you're trying to do is prevent malicious scripts from accidentally being executed on the server. The way I normally handle file uploads like this is:

1. Insert filename, mime-type, etc., into a database with an `auto_increment` ID.
2. Use the ID as the file name - no extension, and place the file in a directory outside of your webroot. This way you're certain nobody can execute the file.
3. When a file is requested, query the database for filename mime-type and id, and send the file to the user with [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile) (follow the link for an example).